# Changing permalinks using mod_rewrite now gives internal server error 500

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I just changed my wordpress permalinks from `domain.com/%year%/%month%/%post-slug%` over to `domain.com/%post-slug%`

I used the following `mod_rewrite` rule to redirect all my older URLs to the new ones.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) http://www.site.com/$1
```

The problem being this redirected all my date based archives

```
domain.com/%year%/%month%/%date%
```

to

```
domain.com/%date%
```

as well which gave out a `404` error. I modified the above code to include a character count (a minimum of `3` and a maximum of `300`) like this in order to tackle the date problem

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]{3,300}+) http://www.site.com/$1
```

But am now getting a `500 Internal Server error`.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule to

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9/-]{3,})$ http://www.site.com/$1
```

Comment: Done Ravi. Still gives me the same 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Yes, the first code I posted works. Except http://site.com/2013/01/28 redirects to http://site.com/28 and gives a 404 error

Comment: Okay, after making sure that first one works just change the plus `+` in it to `{1,}` and see what happens. Use the same source url to test them.

Comment: Ravi, I tried that and set the minimum character count to 4 and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Then `{3,}` would work as well. The issue was `+` after your closing `}` which is invalid and the missing `$` to mark the end of string. Could you please mark this question closed by accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what **%post-slug%** looks like, so I don't know if there is a better way to distinguish between that and a **%date%**, but I'm inferring that **%date%** is a 2-digit number, so you can use a negative lookahead assertion to exclude it. Also, you might want to use **\d** instead of **[0-9]** (they're interchangeable, but the first one is shorter).

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\d{4}/\d{2}/(?!\d{2}$)([a-z0-9\-/]+) http://www.site.com/$1
```

That's more reliable than checking the number of characters, unless you're certain that **%post-slug%** can never be less than three characters. Of course, if **%post-slug%** can ever be a 2-digit number, the rule I suggested will skip it. But in that case, there's no way for a regex to tell the difference.

Also, I'm assuming, based on what you wrote, that nothing can come after **%date%**. If there can be another part after that, change the rule to this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\d{4}/\d{2}/(?!\d{2}($|/))([a-z0-9\-/]+) http://www.site.com/$2
```

(Note the **$2** at the end instead of **$1**)

Comment: When your question is resolved, rather than posting comments thanking people (which often end up getting deleted by mods after a while), you should upvote answers that were helpful and accept the answer that you used or that you feel best addressed the issue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. You do need at least 15 rep to vote, so until you have that you can only accept an answer. Note, however, that you gain +2 rep for accepting an answer, and you already have 6, so that would bring you halfway there.

Comment: Thank you Adi. I have my rep increased now and have upvoted your answer.